# C++ builder (no idea what to do with this code)

Tags: c++builder

Sorry if this is wrong place to ask. I have 2 pieces of code given to me:

```
IdHTTP1->Head("http://dsrt.dyndns.org/files/MAIN.zip");
Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Date));
Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Expires));
Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->LastModified));
```

and also this:

```
TDateTime dt;
AnsiString str = DateToStr(dt);
IdHTTP1->Head("http://dsrt.dyndns.org/files/MAIN.zip");
if(DateToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Date) != str)
  Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Date));
if(DateToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Expires) != str)
  Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Expires));
if(DateToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->LastModified) != str)
  Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->LastModified));
```

Somehow it's supposed to return a date when file was uploaded. But I have no clue how to get c++ builder to compile it. I get syntax errors and "multiple memo1 something" error. Please help.

Comment: *I get syntax errors* without including the exact error message is useless, as is *multiple memo1 something*. If you want help here, include the **exact** error message you're seeing. It's on the screen right in front of you; there is absolutely no excuse for you to fail to include them in your question. If you can't be bothered to provide the actual error you're seeing, why should we make the effort to try and help you?

Comment: E2141 Declaration syntax error, then 3 instances of E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly. Memo1 appeared after fiddling, don't remember what I did.

Comment: Nevermind. Found solution here http://superuser.com/questions/619592/get-modification-time-of-remote-file-over-http-in-bash-script

Comment: That is not a solution to the question you asked here.

Answer (score 2):

`TMemo` is an Embarcadero visual UI component. `TIdHTTP` is a component of the [Indy Project](http://www.indyproject.org), which ships preinstalled in Delphi and C++Builder.

The code you were given is UI-related code, so create UI for it.  In the C++Builder IDE, create a new `TForm` class, drop a `TMemo` on it and name it `Memo1`, and drop a `TIdHTTP` component and name it `IdHTTP1`, and then use something like a button `OnClick` handler to invoke the HTTP code, eg:

Unit1.h:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <IdHTTP.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TMemo *Memo1;
    TButton *Button1;
    TButton *Button2;
    TIdHTTP *IdHTTP1;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button2Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Unit1.cpp:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include <System.Sysutils.hpp>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    IdHTTP1->Head("http://dsrt.dyndns.org/files/MAIN.zip");
    Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Date));
    Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Expires));
    Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->LastModified));
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TDateTime dt = ...; // assign some value
    // see functions such as Date(), Now(), EncodeDateTime(), etc,
    // or use the TDateTimePicker component...

    System::String str = DateToStr(dt);

    IdHTTP1->Head("http://dsrt.dyndns.org/files/MAIN.zip");
    if (DateToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Date) != str)
            Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Date));
    if (DateToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Expires) != str)
            Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->Expires));
    if (DateToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->LastModified) != str)
            Memo1->Lines->Add(DateTimeToStr(IdHTTP1->Response->LastModified));
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That being said, using strings to compare date/time values is not a good idea in general.  Such strings are subject to locale issues.  You are using conversion functions that are dependent on the local machine's current locale, not HTTP's standardized date/time formats.  The `TIdHTTP` properties you are using are `TDateTime` values, where `TIdHTTP` has already translated the HTTP-provided values into binary values in local date/time (based on the local machine's current timezone).  You can compare those values as-is without worrying about any string conversions, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TDateTime dt = ...; // assign some value
    // see functions such as Date(), Now(), EncodeDateTime(), etc,
    // or use the TDateTimePicker component...

    IdHTTP1->Head("http://dsrt.dyndns.org/files/MAIN.zip");
    if (IdHTTP1->Response->Date != dt)
    {
            //...
    }
    if (IdHTTP1->Response->Expires != dt)
    {
            //...
    }
    if (IdHTTP1->Response->LastModified != dt)
    {
            //...
    }
}
```

Doing `TDateTime` comparisons is much more accurate and reliable than string comparisons.  And you are not limited to just the `==` and `!=` operators, you can use the `<` and `>` operators as well:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TDateTime dt = Date();

    IdHTTP1->Head("http://dsrt.dyndns.org/files/MAIN.zip");
    if (IdHTTP1->Response->Date < dt)
    {
            // older than today...
    }
    if (IdHTTP1->Response->Expires < dt)
    {
            // expired prior to today...
    }
    if (IdHTTP1->Response->LastModified < dt)
    {
            // last modified prior to today...
    }
}
```